# Keycloak secure both website and REST API

Tags: java, redirect, keycloak

I have a website (Java EE - Wildfly) secured with the Keycloak adapter. It has to be secure because some data is already preloaded on the site. Now I want to refresh this site in Javascript using my applications REST API, which is secured as a Bearer-Only client.

It works using both JS and Java adapter, but the amount of redirects is distracting.

Access website --> Java adapter redirects you to keycloak --> You login --> Redirect to website --> JS adapter redirects you to keycloak --> it detects you are already logger in --> Redirect to webpage.

Is there any way to improve this flow?

Comment: You should redirect only if your token doesn't exist yet or has expired. So Access website --> Java adapter redirects you to keycloak --> You login --> Redirect to website --> JS adapter checks if token already exists (which it should) --> ....

Comment: JS adapter cannot recieve the token without a redirection as far as I know. Java adapter stores the token internally and only exposes the session cookie, which cannot be used to create additional requests.

Comment: You can avoid using JS adapter provided by KeyCloak and create your own. That's how I did it.

Comment: How did you get the token in the JS app then? Cannot use cookies because the API is not on the same domain.